# Function to join splited received string

Tags: android

I have a function wich checks continuosly the bluetooth's input stream for values:

```
private final Runnable refresh_input = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;
        refresh_handler.postDelayed(refresh_input, 250);
    }
};
```

Then another function that sends a hex string via bluetooth, and then checks the variable above `bt_read_input` to see if the answer is received.

The answer is another hex string like `2b0000`.

If I receive this answer, the the app goes ok. But sometimes the app crashes, and I realized that is because sometimes, instead of received the full string, I receive it in 2 times, something like:

```
1. 2b
2. 0000
```

So I must implement a function that checks this. This function I think could be something like if the byte[] that I receive is 3 bytes long (2b0000 = 3byte), then is ok, but if is smaller that 3, then it should add the received part in a new byte[], check again for the missing part, and add it to get the full byte[].

I started this function this way:

```
private byte[] ConfMsgCheck(byte[] b) {  //b = bt_read_input 
    byte[] ConfByte = new byte[3];

    if (b.length == 3) {
        ConfByte = b;
    }
    else if (b.length < 3) {
        ConfByte = b;
        //here is where I don't know how to continue, because I should do something like a loop
        //that checks again the value of b (bt_read_input) and adds it again to ConfByte.

    }
    return ConfByte;
}
```